# selenium locate no id or name 's elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, c, selenium, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I always locate element by getElementId,

and sent value by using

document.getElementId(id).value = "something".

but I found an button without Id or Name

<  input type="submit" class="button" accesskey="l" value="click me" tabindex="3">

now how can I locate it ???

Comment: Needs more detail. What version of Selenium? (1 or 2/WebDriver). Why are you using Javascript to find the control and set it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
IWebElement element = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button"));
```

Though I don't understand what you are currently using from selenium?